# Como faço para abrir link em nova janela? Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress

Aqui o trecho, estou usando o  Bootstrap.

```
[button-group]  
   [button link="#" dropdown="true" data="toggle,dropdown"] Projetos e Parcerias: [caret][/button]
   [dropdown]
     [dropdown-item link=" ... "] Plano de Trabalho [/dropdown-item]
   [/dropdown]
[/button-group]
```

ele está abrindo o link na mesma pagina, preciso que abra em nova janela.

lembrando que estou no wordpress e estou usando um plugin que permite que criar shortcodes para inserir em campos de texto e serem parseados para html no template.

Comment: Tentou usar target=_blank ?

Comment: tentei sim de algumas formas e sem resultados, se quiser deixar um exemplo eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: Coloca uma tag <a> com target="_blank" dentro do botão

Comment: um exemplo para você https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_a_target

Comment: Pessoal antes de dar downvote na pergunta atente-se que ele está na plataforma wordpress e ele pode estar usando um plugin como [este](https://github.com/MWDelaney/bootstrap-3-shortcodes) que permite que usuário crie shortcodes para inserir em campos de texto e serem parseados para html no template.

Comment: é exatamente esta a situação  @Vinicius.Silva

Comment: @lvr7 poderia expor como ficaria a linha? estou tentando sem sucesso.